# CSS background image only in empty area

Tags: html, css

I have a small div `box` inside a `main` div. The main div uses a background image. I want to add some text in the `box` div and a background image, so that the  background image appears only in the empty area after the text.
So it would be like the text in the box has the background image of main div and the rest of the empty area inside the box div has another background image. Here's the html:

```
        <div class="main">//width = x
           <div class="box"> //width = x
              <span class="text">Text, no bg. </span>  // width = y
              <!-- need bg here in x-y area.-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

hope it makes sense.

Edit: Please check my Jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/zr9Ks/
All I'm trying is to have same background as the main div under the span inside the box div, and push the box div bg after the text.

Comment: why -1? @Elen its very basic example and I've mentioned that main and box div have same width, thats all css.

Comment: paste the CSS even if it is basic

Comment: you should show what you've already tried

Comment: it's a bit unclear. to me it sounds that you need another div after your span with the background you need, then span will have bg of main and the other img will appear lower. is that what you want?

Comment: Does the background image that will be in `box` have a fixed height?

Comment: @Elen if i add another div after the span, and want to display only the background image in that div, how could i do?

Comment: @TimBJames No, the background image is very small, only like a dot, i want to fill the remaining width using that image. The only solution i can think is to set the bg of box, and set the bg of span same as main, but since its gradient image, it doesnt look good.

Comment: hide span text with java script, then show on demand?... consider Hexxagonal answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand better the effect you are after. The only way I can think is using a table making the right cell to be 100% width and the left one no-wrap, check the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LQydR/

Answer (score 1):

The background can be shifted to the left if that is what you need. As @Elen says, it is a bit unclear what you expect. Anyway, shifting the background is something like this:

```
.main {
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('mainbg.png');
}


.text {
    width:100px;
    background:none;
}

.box {
    width:300px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:100px 0;
    background-image:url('boxbg.png');
}
```

Bear in mind that span will not obey to width and will take the width of the text inside unless you make it to display:block.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is same but the only problem is that the .text does not have fixed width, so i can not set background image position.

Comment: That is why you should paste your CSS and maybe a complete example of what you have. Maybe you just need a float after .text with the background image to get the effect you want but without examples you have us guessing.

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/zr9Ks/ ; I dont want the box bg to appear below the text (it should appear only after the text.

Comment: in this case you owe to display span-text and span-bg inline inside a container and set their width 30%/70% or something...

Answer (score 1):

I think i understood what you need:

```
.box {
    width:300px;
    padding-bottom: [height of the img];
    background: url('img.png') repeat-y left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need to do is to declare a different background image/color on `.main` and on `.box` and you're good to go.